# Merge multiple array php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have below arrays.

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) { 
  $query="SELECT member_table.Cur_Position FROM members,member_table WHERE member_table.Member_Id=members.Member_Id AND members.Member_Id=".$_SESSION['Member_Id']." AND member_table.Table_Id=".$i;
  $rs=mysql_query($query);
  $row=mysql_fetch_row($rs);
  $data = array();
  if ($row[0] == "") $row[0] = 0; // Set 0 if value is null
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($row); 
 }
```

output.

```
(
    [0] => 3
)

Array
(
    [0] => 3
)

Array
(
    [0] => 0
)

Array
(
    [0] => 0
)

Array
(
    [0] => 0
)
```

I want result as like below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $a = array(3);
>   $b = array(3);
>   $c = array(0);
>   $d = array(0);
>   $e = array(0);
>
> print_r(**[`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)**($a,$b,$c,$d,$e));
>
> Array
>   (
>       [0] => 3
>       [1] => 3
>       [2] => 0
>       [3] => 0
>       [4] => 0
>   )

EDIT: With your added code, the usage would be something like;

```
$data = array();

for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) { 
  $query="SELECT .....";
  $rs=mysql_query($query);
  $row=mysql_fetch_row($rs);
  if ($row[0] == "") $row[0] = 0; // Set 0 if value is null
  $data = array_merge($data, $row);
}

print_r($data);
```

Comment: I want merge array dynamically. Can you explain more How can i do it?

Comment: @GirishBhutiya The best way to get the answer you need is to be as specific as possible in the question. Please update your question with more info on what you really need help with, preferably code you're written and what you need help improving.

Comment: thanks a lot. i got my exact ans.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function

```
$beginning = array(0 => 'foo');
$end = array(1 => 'bar');
$result = array_merge((array)$beginning, (array)$end);
print_r($result);
```

This will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
)
```

Comment: I want merge array dynamically. Can you explain more How can i do it?

Comment: @girish-bhutiya could you please explain?